# Los tr de una tabla aparecen uno al lado del otro

Tags: html

¿Por qué me pone los `TR` uno al lado del otro, cuando tendría que ponerse uno debajo del otro?

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>col</th>
      <th>Año</th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Enero</th>
      <th>Diciembre</th>
      <th>Noviembre</th>
      <th>Octubre</th>
      <th>Septiembre</th>
      <th>Agosto</th>
      <th>Julio</th>
      <th>Junio</th>
      <th>Mayo</th>
      <th>Abril</th>
      <th>Marzo</th>
      <th>Febrero</th>
      <th>Enero</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">prov</td>
    <td rowspan="3">2018</td>
    <td rowspan="3">
      Coste: <br> Stock: <br> valoracion: <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="3">
      123 <br> 321 <br> 231 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="3">
      123 <br> 321 <br> 231 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="3">
      123 <br> 321 <br> 231 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="3">
      123 <br> 321 <br> 231 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="3">
      123 <br> 321 <br> 231 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="3">
      123 <br> 321 <br> 231 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="3">
      123 <br> 321 <br> 231 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="3">
      123 <br> 321 <br> 231 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="3">
      123 <br> 321 <br> 231 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="3">
      123 <br> 321 <br> 231 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="3">
      123 <br> 321 <br> 231 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="3">
      123 <br> 321 <br> 231 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="3">
      123 <br> 321 <br> 231 <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">prov</td>
    <td rowspan="3">2017</td>
    <td rowspan="3">
      Coste: <br> Stock: <br> valoracion: <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="3">
      123 <br> 321 <br> 231 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="3">
      123 <br> 321 <br> 231 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="3">
      123 <br> 321 <br> 231 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="3">
      123 <br> 321 <br> 231 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="3">
      123 <br> 321 <br> 231 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="3">
      123 <br> 321 <br> 231 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="3">
      123 <br> 321 <br> 231 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="3">
      123 <br> 321 <br> 231 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="3">
      123 <br> 321 <br> 231 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="3">
      123 <br> 321 <br> 231 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="3">
      123 <br> 321 <br> 231 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="3">
      123 <br> 321 <br> 231 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="3">
      123 <br> 321 <br> 231 <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Tienes 15 cabeceras y 16 datos en la primera fila. Eso hace que se descomponga la tabla y ocurra lo que ves.

Comment: Hay 16 de cada una, cabeceras y datos...

Comment: Si, que pense que iba de Enero a diciembre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tener en cuenta que la etiqueta `rowspan` se utiliza para agrupar FILAS

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es nuestra tabla inicial, voy a aplicar `rowspan="4"` a la etiqueta `td` que tiene el contenido `texto1`, permitiendo de esa manera obtener el siguiente resultado,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

podemos observar que ahora `texto1` está ocupando 4 filas, por ende las otras etiquetas se desplazan a la derecha; para solucionar esto me tocará quitar `texto8`, `texto12`, `texto16` para poder obtener un resultado como el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

**Código de Ejemplo**

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>titulo1</th>
            <th>titulo2</th>
            <th>titulo3</th>
            <th>titulo4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4">texto1</td>
            <td>texto2</td>
            <td>texto3</td>
            <td>texto4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>texto5</td>
            <td>texto6</td>
            <td>texto7</td>
            <td>texto8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>texto9</td>
            <td>texto10</td>
            <td>texto11</td>
            <td>texto12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>texto13</td>
            <td>texto14</td>
            <td>texto15</td>
            <td>texto16</td>
        </tr>      
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Es por que el rowspan esta en 3 , creo que buscas esto no?.

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>col</th>
      <th>Año</th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Enero</th>
      <th>Diciembre</th>
      <th>Noviembre</th>
      <th>Octubre</th>
      <th>Septiembre</th>
      <th>Agosto</th>
      <th>Julio</th>
      <th>Junio</th>
      <th>Mayo</th>
      <th>Abril</th>
      <th>Marzo</th>
      <th>Febrero</th>
      <th>Enero</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="1">prov</td>
    <td rowspan="1">2018</td>
    <td rowspan="1">
      Coste: <br> Stock: <br> valoracion: <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1">
      121 <br> 121 <br> 211 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1">
      121 <br> 121 <br> 211 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1">
      121 <br> 121 <br> 211 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1">
      121 <br> 121 <br> 211 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1">
      121 <br> 121 <br> 211 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1">
      121 <br> 121 <br> 211 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1">
      121 <br> 121 <br> 211 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1">
      121 <br> 121 <br> 211 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1">
      121 <br> 121 <br> 211 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1">
      121 <br> 121 <br> 211 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1">
      121 <br> 121 <br> 211 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1">
      121 <br> 121 <br> 211 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1">
      121 <br> 121 <br> 211 <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="1">prov</td>
    <td rowspan="1">2017</td>
    <td rowspan="1">
      Coste: <br> Stock: <br> valoracion: <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1">
      121 <br> 121 <br> 211 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1">
      121 <br> 121 <br> 211 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1">
      121 <br> 121 <br> 211 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1">
      121 <br> 121 <br> 211 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1">
      121 <br> 121 <br> 211 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1">
      121 <br> 121 <br> 211 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1">
      121 <br> 121 <br> 211 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1">
      121 <br> 121 <br> 211 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1">
      121 <br> 121 <br> 211 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1">
      121 <br> 121 <br> 211 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1">
      121 <br> 121 <br> 211 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1">
      121 <br> 121 <br> 211 <br>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1">
      121 <br> 121 <br> 211 <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<style type="text/css">
  table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
```